# subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier doesn't work

Tags: iphone, sim-card

I wrote a Hello World app, and put the following code in *...ViewController.m*:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    networkInfo.subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier = ^(CTCarrier *carrier) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SIM Alert"
                                    message:@"This is an alert."
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    };
}
```

Then I unplugged the SIM card but no alert was shown as expected. Could someone kindly tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the ultimate solution to your question.

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier                  = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *mobileNetworkCode         = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
[networkInfo release];


NSLog(@"Mobile Network Code : %@", mobileNetworkCode);
```

Depending on the mobileNetwork code you can determine whether SIM is present or not on the Device.

Comment: Thanks. But this way needs repeatedly running the check code; no notification. This is what I've done too, but with CTSIMSupportCopyMobileSubscriberIdentity.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at apples documentation of CTCarrier some properties, for example [carrierName](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596-CH1-SW1), have a short notice like this:

> If you configure a device for a carrier and then remove the SIM card, this property retains the name of the carrier.

So I would guess the same happens for the rest of the API, since the SIM card isn't replaced by a new one the updateNotifier isn't called.